# How to access docker's tomcat logs and config file, not the local one but server logs?

Tags: tomcat, docker

How to access remote docker's tomcat logs and config file? I tried to access the log files for local docker machine, and successfully retrieved from the docker's tomcat. I am able to see the docker image at the repository, but do not have a clue to access the tomcat logs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little please? What do you mean 'remote docker's tomcat'? What does 'I am able to see the docker image at the repository, but do not have a clue to access the tomcat logs' mean?

Comment: I mean I installed a local docker client and I was able to access the application logs to see errors in my application. But for an image built by jenkins and deployed at docker-registry(which I meant remote), where can I see the logs. The jenkins build is successful while the docker deployment fails, I want to see the logs to track the error.

Comment: You can't 'deploy' anything at Docker Registry. Think of Docker Registry (hub) as github, it is a static repo. If you want to 'deploy' something to make it run, you need to either deploy to a remote container engine like ECS (AWS) or another docker host that you setup & manage (either manually or via a service like Docker Cloud).